# FieldStorage input removes some characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi

Putting "c++" in a input box, my Python script just receives "c".

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <input id="inputtxt" type="text">&nbsp;
    <a onclick="window.location='escapetest.py?q='+document.getElementById('inputtxt').value;">Go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And the python script which receives the request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from cgi import FieldStorage


inputstr = FieldStorage()["q"]

print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
print
print inputstr.value
```

The output is:

> c

Running Python 2.7 (x64) and using Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not properly escaping your value; the `+` character in a [URL-encoded query value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) is the encoded value for a *space*, so really you are printing:

```
"c  "
```

A `c` with two spaces. Use the [`encodeURIComponent()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly escape the input value, where spaces will be replaced by `+` and `+` will be replaced by `%2B`, so that Python can decode that back to `+`:

```html
<a onclick="window.location='escapetest.py?q='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('inputtxt').value);">Go!</a>
```